# How to encrypt .config file Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to encrypt common.config, not the Web.config file. Common.config is in a different location than the web.config. The web.config file is connected to the common.config.

web.config:

```
<appSettings file="C:\Users\ja\Documents\common.config">
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

common.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="This is the Value"/>
</appSettings>`
```

This works for the web.config file:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings c:\Users\ja\Desktop\test\webapp\webapp -prov "RsaRpotectedConfigurationProvider"
```

But when I try to encrypt the common.config file:

`aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings c:\Users\ja\Document\ -prov "RsaRpotectedConfigurationProvider"`

I get this error:

```
The configuration for physical path 'c:\Users\ja\Document\' cannot be opened
```

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround to solve this issue. Hope it helps.

1. Rename your common.config to web.config temporarily.
2. Add configuration as root element to this file. So your common.config will look like as follows.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="This is the Value"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

3. Run encrypt command.

   aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings c:\Users\ja\Document\ -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
4. Open encrypted file and remove Configuration tags.
5. Rename file to Common.config
   PS: I deleted my original comments posted on this thread.

Comment: I get this error: `Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.` In the common.config file were it says  `<appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">`

Comment: After encryption or while encrypting?

Comment: It encrypts fine, when I run the program that error comes up.`

Comment: Try running encryption command without provider. like aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings c:\Users\ja\Document\. Aslo could you post file contents after encryption?

Comment: It still automatically adds `configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"`

Comment: That should be fine. It will need provider value after encryption. In your original post provider name was wrong hence I thought removing it from command so that it will pick default which is again RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.

Comment: Can you please post encrypted file?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you supplied the full path:

c:\Users\ja\Document\

vs

C:\Users\ja\Documents\common.config

If the syntax requires the directory, Document is still missing the 's'

Comment: It looks like the path parameter is supposed to point to a web application. Perhaps move the common.config to the root of an application rather than the Documents folder?

Comment: The same way it decrypts the web.config.